# Can not use template in package for meteor v0.9.3.1

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

recent days I study meteor js framework , i want to write a package for meteor, but when i try  a package, i have a problem about template

in my package.js

```
   api.use([
    'templating',
    "coffeescript",
  ], "client");

  api.addFiles([
    'client/breadcrumb.coffee',
    'client/helpers.coffee',
    'client/views/breadcrumb/crumb.html'
  ], 'client');

  api.use(['coffeescript'], 'server');

  api.addFiles('server/breadcrumb.coffee', 'server');
```

in my helper.coffee i use snippet code like this:

```
  Template.breadcrumbs.helpers ->
  crumbs: () ->
    Breadcrumb.getCrumbs()
```

And when I include my package on my app it not working.
This is errors:

```
        Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined helpers.coffee:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Breadcrumb' of undefined global-imports.js:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_category.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_contact.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_contact_detail.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_post.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_post_form.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_user.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.about.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.contact.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.home.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.layout.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.404.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_breadcrumb.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_header.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.dashboard_slidebar.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.flash.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.footer.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.header.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.loading.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Deps is not defined dashboard_category.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Deps is not defined dashboard_contact.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Deps is not defined dashboard_post.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined dashboard_user.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined dashboard.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined client.coffee.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined collections.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleSchema is not defined schema.js:6
Error: Spacebars is not defined
ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
    at null._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled.js?724142103f86896bf7ab0a57672b34086f989b24:634:12)
    at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1853:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1795:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2029:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1794:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:476:11)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1793:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1847:10

> Before: 630ms (diff: 630ms)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:738:12
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:774:4
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:1022:3

> Before: 676ms (diff: 46ms)
    at Array.forEach (native) reporters.js?1413185929295:67
Error: Exception in defer callback:
ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
    at null._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_layout.js?080dc95e770e3130757bf6af69fd0abb99573ae4:95:10)
    at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1853:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1795:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2029:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1794:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:476:11)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1793:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1847:10

> Before: 657ms (diff: 657ms)
    at usePostMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:376:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:405:3
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:410:4
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?012a26290d9cb731a3b52b396e571c8159d11236:1022:3
```

Comment: Is the breadcrumbs template itself in crumbs.html?  If so, you'll need to add the html file before you add the helpers.coffee.  I think you can do this by changing the array order, but I'd separate it into two `api.addFiles` calls, with crumbs.html added first.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a load order issue : Meteor requires that a template has to be declared in Spacebars before you can reference it to define its helpers in JS.

By stating in the package source files listing that you want the Spacebars HTML to load BEFORE the JS counterpart, your error should disappear.

```
api.addFiles([
  'client/views/breadcrumb/crumb.html',
  'client/helpers.coffee',
  'client/breadcrumb.coffee'
], 'client');
```